# Issues to write floating point values using RasterIO

Tags: floating-point, raster, gdal

I’m writing a code in C++ (MSVS 2013), using GDAL, function RasterIO, and I’m having trouble to write point values.

As described in the API Tutorial, I use the following code to write a line in my raster file:

```
poBand->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, j, nXSize, 1, pafWriteline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
```

where:

```
pafWriteline = (float *)CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nXSize);
```

However, later, when I read this same line using the code:

```
poBand->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, j, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
```

all values in pafScanline were rounded (looks like integers).

Anybody have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How was the raster created? E.g., does `poDriver->Create` also specify `GDT_Float32`?

Comment: Hello Mike. I just used the following code to create my raster file (based in the original): `poDstDS = poDriver->CreateCopy(pszDstFilename, poDataset, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: What was the raster data type (`eBandType`) of `pszDstFilename`? You can get this from the command line with gdalinfo.

Comment: I got `GDT_Unknown`. Do you know how to change my bands type, when I copy, to `GDT_Float32`?

Comment: So your question is, effectively, how to somehow create a raster based on another, but with a different data type. Great question, but I'm not sure how. See [gdal_translate.cpp source](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/apps/gdal_translate.cpp) to get an idea how the `gdal_translate -of Float32` command does it.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your help! I solve this issue using `Create` instead of `CreateCopy`. The translate source manage the translation copying the info into variables and use them to create a new raster file. Unfortunately this is the only way it works at the moment. Hope the GDAL developers add this feature in the future.